# Confused by the Qt's event loop system?

Tags: c++, qt

The documents say the Qt's event loop is FIFO.
But I am a little bit confused by the documentation, so if:
I have two buttons, the first one will do:

```
on_click_button_one(){
    list.append(new_element);
}
```

the second one will do:

```
on_click_button_two(){
  while(!list.empty()){
    list.remove_top();
  }
}
```

Since the list can be very big, it takes some time for the list to be cleared. But if I click the button one during the clearing process, what will happen?
The two on_click_button functions are in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, because your `GUI` will not interact with user because all your main thread deletes list, if it requires `5` seconds, then `5` seconds your `GUI` will be freezed.

If you will call `processEvents()` on every iteration, to do your GUI unfreezed, then you should just disable your first button or use `QProgressDialog` to show the progress of operation.

AFAIK function in main thread and function in another thread can execute at same time(parallel) but 2 functions in same thread can't execute at the same time. If you don't use something like `std::thread`, `QtConcurrent` or `QThread` then I think you can be sure that these 2 slots lives in one thread and it will never be executed at the same time.

Comment: But if the two slots are in another thread, not the main thread?

Comment: @Nyaruko AFAIK function in main thread and function in another thread can execute at same time(parallel) but 2 functions in same thread can't execute at the same time. If you don't use something like std::thread QtConCurrent or QThread then I think you can be sure that these 2 slots lives in one thread and it will never be executed at the same time.